# why every class in java is a subclass of object?

Tags: java, oop

The Object class, in the java.lang package, sits at the top of the class hierarchy tree. Every class is a descendant, direct or indirect, of the Object class. Every class you use or write inherits the instance methods of Object.
why do we need a class that is the super class of every other class in java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is how Java is being designed. Java treats everything (except pirmitives) as an object including your self-defined objects.

There is an advantage by making all newly created classes to extend from Object. It allows common methods and attributes to be automatically available upon creation of a new object.

Some of the common methods are for example: `toString()` and `equals()`..etc

Answer (score 1):

It's useful to have a common behavior/interface among all types for operations like comparison among other things.

It's also useful for when you want to make an array or other collection which contains or can contain different types.

Answer (score 1):

Having `Object` as an implicit base class of all Java classes helps you write code that does not depend on the precise type, such as a collection, a class that produces string representations, and so on. See documentation of [`java.lang.Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) for a list of methods what every class supports "out of the box".

This is by no means a required feature of *all* languages: there are other languages where there is no mandatory common subclass. Doing it this way was a choice of the language designers.